# im stuck at an error method not found, Method not found: 'Void EPS.BAL.ViewModel.PersonalTaskModel.set_PendingTaskStatus(System.Web.Mvc.SelectList)

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, model-view-controller

I created an action method named `DueTask` and a View for it. I'm calling it through an icon:

```
<li>
  <a href="@Url.Action("DueTask", "FundingCompany")" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Due Task">
    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></div>
  </a>
</li>
```

However when clicking on the icon its throwing an error and it's not hitting the action method. I don't have any method named that.

> Error : Method not found: 'Void EPS.BAL.ViewModel.PersonalTaskModel.set_PendingTaskStatus(System.Web.Mvc.SelectList)
>    stack trace:
>   [MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void EPS.BAL.ViewModel.PersonalTaskModel.set_PendingTaskStatus(System.Web.Mvc.SelectList)'.]
>      EPS.Controllers.FundingCompanyController.DueTask() +0
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +61
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14

```
public ActionResult DueTask()
{
  int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
  PersonalTaskModel pendingView = new PersonalTaskModel();
  List<SelectListItem> patientCat = new List<SelectListItem>();
  patientCat.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--SELECT--", Value = "2" });
  patientCat.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "All", Value = "2" });
  //patientCat.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Minor", Value = "2" });
  ViewBag.PatientCategory = patientCat.ToList();
  var PendingTaskStatus = _repo.GetMasterDataByCategoryID(ConstantHelper.GetCategoryID(CatergoryConstant.PendingtaskStatus)).OrderBy(x => x.ItemID).ToList();
  ViewBag.PendingTaskStatus = new SelectList(PendingTaskStatus, "ItemID", "MasterData");
  pendingView.PendingTaskStatus = new SelectList(PendingTaskStatus, "ItemID", "MasterData");
  var TaskList = _repo.GetAllPersonalTaskByUserID(UserID);
  ViewBag.DueTask = TaskList.Count();
  return View();
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your questions properly. This was unreadable before I edited it

Comment: With regard to the error it looks like a problem with the SelectList you're trying to populate in the View.

Comment: but its not even hitting the action, i have a breakpoint on Actionmethod

Comment: you have  ''set_PendingTaskStatus'' method or property in your viewmodel  ?? seems like you have some problem in view model that you are using in your view ..